# Unable to login in Camunda Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, camunda

I configured camunda Kubernetes pods on my EKS cluster and accessed my dashboard using the ALB but when I try to login into my dashboard I got the error.

**Error: Wrong credentials, locked user or missing access rights to application**

The creds which I used are demo -> username and demo -> password. I don't know what is the issue, and why I am not able to login into my camunda dashboard?

Logs:

```
Configure database
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.58
06-May-2022 10:41:24.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 15 2022 14:37:38 UTC
06-May-2022 10:41:24.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.58.0
06-May-2022 10:41:24.478 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
06-May-2022 10:41:24.478 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.188-104.359.amzn2.x86_64
06-May-2022 10:41:24.478 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
06-May-2022 10:41:24.479 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
06-May-2022 10:41:24.479 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.9+11-alpine-r1
06-May-2022 10:41:24.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Alpine
06-May-2022 10:41:24.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /camunda
06-May-2022 10:41:24.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /camunda
06-May-2022 10:41:24.535 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.538 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.538 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.538 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.541 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
06-May-2022 10:41:24.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/camunda/conf/logging.properties
06-May-2022 10:41:24.542 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-May-2022 10:41:24.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
06-May-2022 10:41:24.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
06-May-2022 10:41:24.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
06-May-2022 10:41:24.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
06-May-2022 10:41:24.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/camunda
06-May-2022 10:41:24.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/camunda
06-May-2022 10:41:24.545 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/camunda/temp
06-May-2022 10:41:24.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/../lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
06-May-2022 10:41:26.029 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-May-2022 10:41:26.086 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2531] milliseconds
06-May-2022 10:41:28.541 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08046 Found Camunda Platform configuration in CATALINA_BASE/CATALINA_HOME conf directory [/camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml] at 'file:/camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml'
06-May-2022 10:41:29.108 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'ProcessApplicationEventListenerPlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
06-May-2022 10:41:29.138 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'SpinProcessEnginePlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
06-May-2022 10:41:29.146 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormatProvider[name = application/json]
06-May-2022 10:41:29.692 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormatProvider[name = application/xml]
06-May-2022 10:41:29.756 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormat[name = application/xml]
06-May-2022 10:41:29.758 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormat[name = application/json]
06-May-2022 10:41:29.758 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'ConnectProcessEnginePlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
06-May-2022 10:41:30.288 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo CNCT-01004 Discovered provider for connector id 'http-connector' and class 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.impl.HttpConnectorImpl': 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.impl.HttpConnectorProviderImpl'
06-May-2022 10:41:30.292 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo CNCT-01004 Discovered provider for connector id 'soap-http-connector' and class 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.soap.impl.SoapHttpConnectorImpl': 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.soap.impl.SoapHttpConnectorProviderImpl'
06-May-2022 10:41:30.799 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo FEEL/SCALA-01001 Spin value mapper detected
06-May-2022 10:41:30.976 INFO [main] org.camunda.feel.FeelEngine.<init> Engine created. [value-mapper: CompositeValueMapper(List(org.camunda.feel.impl.JavaValueMapper@2b960a7, org.camunda.spin.plugin.impl.feel.integration.SpinValueMapper@31dfc6f5)), function-provider: org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.scala.function.CustomFunctionTransformer@2975a9e, clock: SystemClock, configuration: Configuration(false)]
06-May-2022 10:41:43.168 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-00001 Process Engine default created.
06-May-2022 10:41:43.174 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-14014 Starting up the JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.RuntimeContainerJobExecutor].
06-May-2022 10:41:43.184 INFO [Thread-4] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-14018 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.RuntimeContainerJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
06-May-2022 10:41:43.188 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08048 Camunda Platform sucessfully started at 'Apache Tomcat/9.0.58'.
06-May-2022 10:41:43.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
06-May-2022 10:41:43.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
06-May-2022 10:41:43.308 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/ROOT]
06-May-2022 10:41:52.629 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:41:52.727 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [9,419] ms
06-May-2022 10:41:52.732 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda]
06-May-2022 10:42:01.373 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:02.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda] has finished in [10,070] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:02.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda-invoice]
06-May-2022 10:42:07.617 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-07015 Detected @ProcessApplication class 'org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication'
06-May-2022 10:42:07.694 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:07.706 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08024 Found processes.xml file at file:/camunda/webapps/camunda-invoice/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/processes.xml
06-May-2022 10:42:07.771 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08023 Deployment summary for process archive 'InvoiceProcessApplication': 

        invoiceBusinessDecisions.dmn
        invoice.v2.bpmn

06-May-2022 10:42:08.500 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-07021 ProcessApplication 'InvoiceProcessApplication' registered for DB deployments [2b9ccbc2-cd26-11ec-ae41-6a7197e6c0b5, 2ad69588-cd26-11ec-ae41-6a7197e6c0b5]. Will execute process definitions 

        invoice[version: 2, id: invoice:2:2bb73195-cd26-11ec-ae41-6a7197e6c0b5]
        ReviewInvoice[version: 1, id: ReviewInvoice:1:2b215a2e-cd26-11ec-ae41-6a7197e6c0b5]
        invoice[version: 1, id: invoice:1:2b1dfecc-cd26-11ec-ae41-6a7197e6c0b5]
Deployment does not provide any case definitions.
06-May-2022 10:42:08.507 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormatProvider[name = application/json]
06-May-2022 10:42:08.512 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormatProvider[name = application/xml]
06-May-2022 10:42:08.513 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormat[name = application/xml]
06-May-2022 10:42:08.513 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormat[name = application/json]
06-May-2022 10:42:08.868 INFO [main] org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication.startProcessInstances No new instances of Invoice Receipt version 1 started, there are 3 instances running
06-May-2022 10:42:09.063 INFO [main] org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication.startProcessInstances No new instances of Invoice Receipt version 2 started, there are 3 instances running
06-May-2022 10:42:09.067 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08050 Process application InvoiceProcessApplication successfully deployed
06-May-2022 10:42:09.068 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda-invoice] has finished in [6,260] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:09.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda-welcome]
06-May-2022 10:42:14.020 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:14.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/camunda-welcome] has finished in [4,964] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:14.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/docs]
06-May-2022 10:42:17.709 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:17.713 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/docs] has finished in [3,673] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:17.716 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/engine-rest]
06-May-2022 10:42:21.971 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:22.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/engine-rest] has finished in [4,487] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:22.203 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/examples]
06-May-2022 10:42:26.610 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:26.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/examples] has finished in [4,485] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:26.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/h2]
06-May-2022 10:42:30.616 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:30.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/h2] has finished in [3,962] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:30.655 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/host-manager]
06-May-2022 10:42:34.337 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:34.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [3,689] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:34.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/camunda/webapps/manager]
06-May-2022 10:42:37.194 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-May-2022 10:42:37.200 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/camunda/webapps/manager] has finished in [2,855] ms
06-May-2022 10:42:37.204 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-May-2022 10:42:37.221 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [71128] milliseconds
06-May-2022 10:45:13.988 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.impl.web.TasklistApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:13.996 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.impl.web.TasklistApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:13.996 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.RestExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.impl.web.TasklistApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:13.997 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.JacksonConfigurator from Application class org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.impl.web.TasklistApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:13.997 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.impl.web.TasklistApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:18.986 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.004 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.007 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.UserAuthenticationResource from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.007 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.RestExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.012 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.SetupResource from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.012 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.JacksonConfigurator from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.012 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.plugin.resources.AdminPluginsRootResource from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 10:45:19.012 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.admin.impl.web.AdminApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.389 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.393 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.MultipartPayloadProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.393 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ProcessEngineExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.394 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.395 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.JacksonConfigurator from Application class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 13:45:40.395 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.EngineRestApplication
06-May-2022 14:13:20.128 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost The host [_] is not valid
 Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:78)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:793)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:375)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
06-May-2022 14:16:06.631 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.web.CockpitApplication
06-May-2022 14:16:06.634 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.plugin.resources.CockpitPluginsRootResource from Application class org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.web.CockpitApplication
06-May-2022 14:16:06.636 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.RestExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.web.CockpitApplication
06-May-2022 14:16:06.636 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.JacksonConfigurator from Application class org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.web.CockpitApplication
06-May-2022 14:16:06.636 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.web.CockpitApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.649 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.658 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.JaxRsTwoNamedProcessEngineRestServiceImpl from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.658 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.JsonParseExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.658 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.JaxRsTwoDefaultProcessEngineRestServiceImpl from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.659 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.659 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
06-May-2022 14:32:00.659 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.ProcessEngineExceptionHandler from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
  org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.processApplication RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.mapper.MultipartPayloadProvider from Application class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
```

If anyone knows any solution then please share it with me.

Comment: In order to help you we need to understand first how you deploy and configure Camund Platform and which version you're using right now.

Comment: I deployed my camunda using helm charts in a private EKS cluster. And I am accessing it using the ingress controller. But unable to login into it.

Comment: Which helm charts you are using. Can you link the github repo or the helm repo, so I know what you're using?

Comment: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform I am using this one and i am also using RDS as database instead of using default one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Make sure to use one of the supported databases https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/introduction/supported-environments/#databases . Follow up question did you followed the example guide here https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-helm/tree/main/charts/camunda-bpm-platform#database ?

Comment: What is the log on the server showing?

Comment: @rob2universe This is the logs coming: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [65610] milliseconds
06-May-2022 06:20:12.975 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost The host [_] is not valid
 Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:78)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45)
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:298)

Comment: There has no be more. Please add startup log to question

Comment: @rob2universe Question Edited. please reply now if you know solution.

Comment: The host [_] name cannot be resolved. We need to see more of your deployment configuration to tell why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learn from you that the solution is enabling sticky-sessions using cookies to ingress controller (K8s nginx). This would ensure that all requests from a given user are directed to the same instance over a configurable period of time.

It's a good solution and resolve the login cookpit.

But i've a important question:

into my architecture there are:

1. 1 microservices camunda with 2 POD
2. Others microservices that call api rest camunda fecthAndLock.

if i enable sticky-sessions, lose the benefit of scaling pod? All requests from a microservice A to Camunda user are directed to the same POD?

[image]

Thank you,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 3):

I've got similar issue - not being able to login with default credentials. My setup was: 2 pods in kubercluster with postgresql. I found out that the problem was caused by the number of pods. I got CSRF error after login attempts.
The solution for me was enabling sticky-sessions to ingress. You can find out how to do it [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/).

Comment: This worked for use too, we have a slightly different setup with ingress. We could solve the issue with setting the following properties:     traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "true"
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.sticky.cookie.name: sticky